# Display ComboBoxItems in Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I want my `ComboBox` to display `ComboBoxItem`s in multiple columns like this:

[image]

Can someone tell me how can I do this?

I can use this:

```
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
```

But it doesn't let me specify where I want to end a column.

Is there a way to make the `ComboBox` use the `Grid.Column` property in the `ComboBoxItem`s so that I can add the `ComboBoxItem`s in different columns?

Comment: have you seen somewhere like that? I am sure it is possible, but lots of non standard stuff.

Comment: But that does not look like a ComboBox.  Have you looked at ListView GridView?

Comment: @Dilshod I haven't seen. That's a context menu I coded.

Comment: @Blam That's a context menu I coded. I didn't look at ListView/GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the ItemsPanelTemplate to a WrapPanel.

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical" Width="100" Height="50" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>

    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 2" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 3" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 4" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 5" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 5" />

</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a custom `Panel` to your project and set it as the `ItemsPanel` like this:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Controls:ColumnPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

You can find out how to create custom `Panel`s in [this tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html).

EDIT >>>

I've just thought that you might be able to get this simple layout from an existing `Panel`: the `WrapPanel`... give me a moment while I investigate this.

Further EDIT >>>

Ok, so there are these properties on a `WrapPanel`; `ItemWidth` and `ItemHeight`. This is a bit of a hack, but if you set the `ItemWidth` property of the `WrapPanel` to half of the `Width` of the `WrapPanel`, then you'll have a basic two column `Panel`. The only problem is that you'll have to hard code these values.

Personally, I would recommend taking the time to create a simple re-usable `ColumnPanel` control that allows you to set how many columns that you want in it. I have one and have found many uses for it... they can also go into `ListBox` and other collection controls.